# Looking for a JQL-like Javascript search input/library

Tags: javascript, search, jql

I'm in need of a search input component that can accept and parse search input strings in a format similar to Jira's JQL, including providing type-ahead or dropdown aids that convey valid operators, searchable attributes and valid attribute values.

It does not need to be a sophisticated as Jira's JQL, but rather support basic text/number comparison operators (=, <, >, etc), logical operators (AND, OR, NOT, !, etc) and logical expression grouping (parens for order of operation).  I assume this library would accept configuration that specifies valid searchable attributes, their relevant comparison operators and optionally a list of valid values.

This library would ideally produce JSON that contains a normalized representation of the desired search criteria.

Is anyone aware of such a library/framework before I attempt to build one myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A good starting point "Parsing in JavaScript: Tools and Libraries" https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/